# How fit pairwise ranking models in XGBoost?

Tags: search, ranking, xgboost, gbm

As far as I know, to train learning to rank models, you need to have three things in the dataset:

- label or relevance
- group or query id
- feature vector

For example, the [Microsoft Learning to Rank dataset](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/beijing/projects/letor/letor4dataset.aspx) uses this format (label, group id, and features).

```
1 qid:10 1:0.031310 2:0.666667 ...
0 qid:10 1:0.078682 2:0.166667 ...
```

I am trying out XGBoost that utilizes GBMs to do pairwise ranking. They have an [example for a ranking task](https://github.com/dmlc/xgboost/tree/master/demo/rank) that uses the C++ program to learn on the Microsoft dataset like above.

However, I am using their Python wrapper and cannot seem to find where I can input the group id (`qid` above). I can train the model using just the features and relevance score, but I am missing something.

Here is a sample script.

```
gbm = XGBRegressor(objective="rank:pairwise")

X =  np.random.normal(0, 1, 1000).reshape(100, 10)
y = np.random.randint(0, 5, 100)

gbm.fit(X, y) ### --- no group id needed???

print gbm.predict(X)

# should be in reverse order of relevance score
print y[gbm.predict_proba(X)[:, 1].argsort()][::-1]
```

Comment: I also come across this problem, but what kind of set_group should I pass to the function? when I construct a numpy or list I get error like this:
d:\build\xgboost\xgboost-git\dmlc-core\include\dmlc\./logging.h:235: [12:03:09] D:\Build\xgboost\xgboost-git\src\c_api\c_api.cc:342: Check failed: (src.info.group_ptr.size()) == (0) slice does not support group structure
@amyrit

Answer (score 12, accepted):

According to the [XGBoost documentation](https://xgboost.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorials/input_format.html), XGboost expects:

- the examples of a same group to be consecutive examples,
- a list with the size of each group (which you can set with `set_group` method of `DMatrix` in Python).

Comment: Thanks, looks like API for model buildling (`sklearn.py`) is a little incomplete for the Python package.

Comment: Link to documentation is dead

Comment: @user45254 thanks for pointing out. I've not used XGBoost for a long while, but I think https://xgboost.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorials/input_format.html is the right link now, can you confirm?

Comment: @amyrit yes that looks correct!

Comment: Thanks, I updated the answer to reflect the change.

Answer (score 6):

`set_group` is very important to ranking, because only the scores in one group are comparable.
You can sort data according to their scores in their own group.

For easy ranking, you can use my [xgboostExtension](https://github.com/bigdong89/xgboostExtension).